# CSS border moving div

Tags: css

I'm using custom Leaflet markers, and am adding a border to a marker that's been clicked on. However, adding the marker moves the div element. I have an animated gif to show what I mean:

[image]

What I want is for the green circle to stay in place when the golden border is added. My css:

```
.marker-cluster-div {
background-color: #00ff00;
min-width: 40px;
min-height: 40px;
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 50%;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px;
}

.selectedMarker {
border: 10px solid gold;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You're not using the border when hovered but using another div which is causing you to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a hard box-shadow instead of a border

```
.selectedMarker {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px gold;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The box-shadow does not change the amount of space an element occupies on a page.

Alternatively, add a transparent border when your div is not hovered over.

Comment: This was the one I ended up using. Adding a transparent border for some reason did not work for me correctly: it increased the size of the marker icon. This solution worked great.

Comment: Note that [box-shadow doesn't work in IE8-](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). Personally I don't think that's an issue, but just so you know.

Comment: Neither does `border-radius` :) For this browser, you can use the `outline` property (which behaves kinda like `border` but it's always rectangular and doesn't add up to the space an element occupies on a page).

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! Luckily, this application does not have to support pre-stone-age software.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent this.

```css
.marker-cluster-div {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.marker-cluster-div:hover {
  border: 10px solid gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker-cluster-div"></div>
```

Comment: Works very well, thanks for your time! However, the golden border is placed on top of the circle div, instead of around it like in the gif I posted.

Comment: Using `border-box` in this case would make the content area smaller (or even too small)

Comment: @MichałDudak - Yea I know that and btw, your solution was great!

Answer (score 1):

The position is based on left and top values of the div. They are counted including the border, so the div doesn't actually move, but the div (including its border) grows.

To prevent this, the easiest solution would be to always give it a border, but make that border transparent:

```
.marker-cluster-div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.selectedMarker {
  border-color: gold;
}
```